# Where to change the font of headlines in classicthesis?

Tags: classicthesis

I am using a modified template of dissertation that uses [classicThesis](https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis?lang=en).

**Problem:** The font used for many headings/titles* are not consistent with the main document.

**Goal:** I want to find where and how I should make the change.

*By "headings/titles" I mean "dissertation title", "abstract title", "dedication title", Acknowledgements title, "table of contents title", and "chapter titles". Sections and subsections use the same fonts as the main text.

**Example**:This screenshot below shows a few of those titles. As you can see, font used for "Motivation" is what I need for all titles.

[image]

[image]

**See my [arsclassica.sty](https://pastebin.com/WxbMhJ4C).**

---

Using the code snippet below, I can change the size of all those things (although only in TOC), but not the font:

```
\newcommand\myformatchapter[1]{% 
    \vbox to \ht\strutbox{ 
    \setbox0=\hbox{\chapterNumber\thechapter\hspace{10pt}\vline\ } 
    \advance\hsize-\wd0 \advance\hsize-10pt\raggedright 
    \spacedallcaps{#1}\vss}} 
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block] 
       {\normalfont\Large}  % <------------ adjust the Chapter title's font size
       {\textcolor{halfgray}{\chapterNumber\thechapter} % <--- set color of Chapter number
       \hspace{10pt}\vline\ }{10pt} 
    {\formatchapter}   
    
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\large}      % <--- overrides chapter title font in toc
```

Comment: Does redefining `\ct@altfont` (with `\makeatletter` set) work? E.g. `\renewcommand*{\ct@altfont}{\sffamily}`

Comment: @Davislor thanks, but no. I tried this: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ct@altfont}{\sffamily}
\makeatother`

Comment: Since classicThesis is based on ``scrreprt``, could a simple ``\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\large}`` work?

Comment: This is many questions in one because table of contents is printed independently of titles, as are page headers. Open classicthesis.sty and search for all those `\titleformat{}`, `\cft...{}` pretty much every command with `\spacedlowsmallcaps`, `\spacedallcaps`. They do all the magic, change one by one.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish. If smallcaps and Iwona fonts of arsclassica are bothering you, something like `\renewcommand{\ct@caps}{}` should do.

Comment: If you don't want anything uppercased as well, play with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{#1}` and `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{#1}`

Comment: @shekura, thanks. Unfortunately didn't have any effect, at least the way I used it.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip, thanks. You last suggestion actually worked. But its impact is a little messy. I do want the chapter names to be upper-case. I only don't want that font anywhere in the document. How to get rid of that font? (Is that Iwona?)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip, unfortunately they don't have any impact. Just added my `arsclassica.sty` to the question. Maybe that could give you a clue?

Comment: Yes, that's Iwona. Then `\renewcommand*{\ct@altfont}{}` or `\renewcommand*{\ct@altfont}{\rmfamily}` - of course, only after classicthesis package(s) have been loaded. I see a few more `\sffamily` in classicthesis-arsclassica.sty. Copy those commands or edit the file changing to `\rmfamily` (that's roman instead of sans serif).

Comment: OK I see... those are old files. `\sffamily` to `\rmfamily` should do.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip, could you please tell me exactly what you mean by "copy those commands or edit the file"? What should I copy, and where to? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was: how to switch from sans serif Iwona fonts of arsclassica to roman/serif fonts.
Answer: **EITHER** copy all commands containing `\sffamily` from (classicthesis-)arsclassica.sty to your tex file, below the call to classicthesis, and replace all `\sffamily` with `\rmfamily`
**OR** edit your own copy of arsclassica.sty directly (the one that comes with the template), replacing all `\sffamily` with `\rmfamily`.

Comment: replaced as suggested in both `arsclassica-settings.tex` and `arsclassica.sty`, and worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: If you update `arsclassica.sty`, please at least edit a copy in your local TeX tree.